# I want to populate a comboBox with data from a Column I only want one instance of the item in the column in the comboBox

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

Using Excel-VBA

I have a list about 100 items long with only 5 types of items in the list. an example: Black, White, Red, Blue, green.   How can i populate the combo box with just the 5 Colors(items) and not all 100 in a drop-down list?

I don't have code to start with that's why i'm asking.

[image: DropDown]

Then i need to populate comboBox2 with only the items in B that correspond to A

Comment: If the list is not dynamic, i.e. additional colors will be added/removed at a later point, create a separate table with the distinct options to use as reference. It is also possible in VBA, but this method is a lot easier.

Comment: The list is dynamic this is where my problem is.

Comment: @JASH Then copy/paste that row to anther sheet and use the remove duplicates feature and populate your box with that. Probably the fastest way.

Comment: combobox.additem "Red", combobox.additem "Blue", .. ... You can do this five times, which is not the point of the question. Insert an image and explain your question in detail.

Answer (score 1):

This code will copy unique values in Column A to Column B very efficiently.

```
Range("A:A").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("B1"), Unique:=True
```

You can change "A:A" to whatever range you need, it will also take blank as a unique as it sits right now. Add the combobox population based on values in B.